# PayPal SDK API/Account Declining All Cards

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, sdk

I recently sold one of my web platforms which takes advantage of PayPal's PHP SDK. I've ran the platform for a few months with no issues. Recently I sold this platform and upon changing the API credentials to the buyers I get returned a response code 400.

```
Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-7EV93298TM0891705K5XGLLA/execute. {"name":"INSTRUMENT_DECLINED","details":[],"message":"The instrument presented  was either declined by the processor or bank, or it can't be used for this payment.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#INSTRUMENT_DECLINED","debug_id":"cfdefedc8b7b2"}
```

Now obviously you may assume it's as easy as the error states, the card is being declined but upon switching back to my API credentials the payments go through with no issue.

The buyer has contacted PayPal support which blames the issue on my platform.

I've had the buyer send screenshots of his account eligibility from the developers.paypal/api section. Everything necessary looks to be enabled.

I can confirm the API information provided is correct as during the payment flow I am redirected to PayPal which I am able to view the buyers email/business name in the header. I check out as a guest, enter my credit card information and when I am sent back I receive a response code 400.

Very odd, can you think of any account issues that could cause this? Anything else? I've searched all over the web. I am the seller so I can't really talk to PayPal support about the buyers account so it's been kind of challenging to have the buyer who has less computer/code knowledge talk to support regarding this issue.

note: the buyers account is a business account and his currency is USD (same as the platform).